# Render troff file on terminal like the man outputs on terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, man, conversion, groff

I was trying to render the troff file https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/blob/master/common/man/C/backintime-config.1 in terminal.

How can I make the output (using `cat` or some other utility) look like the way man outputs troff file in the terminal?

Do I need to convert the troff file to some format understood by the terminal?

---

Note: I am not looking to export it to pdf or html

Comment: The question does not specify an operating system, and `man` built upon `groff` exists on at least (older) FreeBSD and Linux-based operating systems.

Comment: I'm really unfamiliar with the subject, but `groffer --tty your_file` is probably an easy way. (I see that `groffer` is provided by the groff package on Ubuntu, which is likely not installed by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
man "${Path-To-Troff-File}"
```

Comment: It's not that simple.  With some implementations of `man` this only works if the path contains a directory prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (depending on system): use the `groff` tool with the appropriate `troff` post processing macro for output to a TTY device, e.g. `utf8`.

```bash
# To stdout
$ groff -man -T utf8 file.1

# From archive via pipe
$ zcat file.1.gz | groff -man -T utf8 -i

# Pass to less
$ groff -man -T utf8 file.1 | less -R
...
```

One can use `grog` to detect what macro to use, and optionally execute by using `--run` and passing options to groff. For example:

```bash
$ grog file.1
groff -man file.1
```

```bash
$ grog --run -T utf8 file.1
groff -T utf8 -man file.1
[DOC]
...
```

- [groff](http://man.he.net/man1/groff) - front-end for the groff document formatting system.
- [grog](http://man.he.net/man1/grog) - guess options for a following groff command.

---

- [groff_tmac](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/groff_tmac.5.html) - macro files in the GNU roff typesetting system.
- [groff_man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_man.7.html) - compose manual pages with GNU roff.
- [grotty](http://man.he.net/man1/grotty) - groff driver for typewriter-like devices.
- [nroff](http://man.he.net/man1/nroff) – use groff to format documents for TTY devices.
- [troff](http://man.he.net/man1/troff) - the troff processor of the groff text formatting system.